# Sequel Pro for Mac - MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4)

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, centos, sequelpro

I can SSH to my server and then connect to MySQL just fine using terminal.  I use the same credentials in Sequel Pro and I get this message:

> MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4)

I never had this problem before.  It just started recently after my colleague made some server adjustments (he is unfortunately unreachable for a few days now).  Any idea why I can connect just fine via terminal (command line) but not with Sequel Pro?  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like iptables. Check by going `service iptables stop`. Don't leave it off, but start there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This ended up being because of changes made to iptables.  Can't get into the details but rules were made stricter.